# Google Chrome Canary - on Ubuntu 14.04 how to get it?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, google-chrome, hardware, chromium

I need to test some hardware on Ubuntu 14.04 which are all working on Mac and Windows 8.1. But Ubuntu 14.04 old Google Chrome is available via apt-get

How do I get the Google Chrome Canary or nightly developer versions via apt-get? I need to test lot of hardware with Canary version which were resolved for Mac and Windows but untested still for Linux because of Ubuntu 14.04 not shifting the latest Canary.

Can anyone please send me quick way to get the full Canary?

Answer (score 6):

The [download page](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html) for Chrome Canary tells me:

> Chrome Canary is currently not available on the linux platform.
>
> You can try Chrome Canary for Windows 32-bit, Windows 64-bit or OSX.

The [list of channels](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel) doesn't show any Canary build for Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 - Download the zip https://download-chromium.appspot.com/

Step 2

```
$ ./chrome --no-sandbox
```

NOTE:

```
cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
sudo ln -sf libudev.so.1 libudev.so.0
```

Comment: That is not "canary" ;)

Comment: Never download a browser from a website that you don't recognize. if you do, all the rest of your browsing is made completely and immediately insecure.

Comment: @mlissner That website is being maintained by Chromium team

Comment: Prove it. How do I know I can trust it? How do I know I can trust you? This is a browser we're talking about.

Comment: @mlissner The website is directly mentioned on the Chrome Release Channels page: https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel (although it's true that it's not "canary")